# Storing Date Stored as "MMDDYY" to a Date Variable

Tags: vb6

I am trying to find out if there is a simpler way of storing a date formatted as `MMDDYY` from what I have been doing.

```
Function Insert(Source As String, myString As String, i As Integer) As String
    Insert = Mid(Source, 1, i) & myString & Mid(Source, i + 1, Len(Source) - i)
End Function
```

My method involves using the insert function to insert a forward slash within the string, twice. It's not necessarily a huge burden, but it would be nice to know for future reference. See below:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strDate As String, iDate As Date

    strDate = "100416"
    strDate = Insert(strDate,"/",2) 'MM/DDYY
    strDate = Insert(strDate,"/",5) 'MM/DD/YY
    iDate = CDate(strDate)

End Sub
```

Obviously a number simply formatted as `MMDDYY` could appear as a date that is in decimal form, so VBS doesn't take it very well.

Comment: There is no Insert() in VBScript, so please specify the correct language.

Comment: This is tagged VBScript but neither your code or the answer given uses VBScript syntax, what are you actually using?

Comment: In VBScript you would use something like `Mid()` instead of `Insert()` or build your own version of `Insert()` that uses `Mid()`. I'm guessing the `Insert()` function in your code refers to the `String.Insert()` method in VB.Net??

Comment: I apologize on the `insert` issue. I have updated my question to include my function.

Comment: Still not VBScript as declarations are typeless `As` is not used, only VBA, VB or VB.Net use that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `DateSerial(Y,M,D)`.

Try this, this returns **`100416 --> 10/04/2016`**:

```
strDate = "100416"
WScript.Echo strDate & " --> " & DateSerial(Mid(strDate,5,2),Mid(strDate,1,2),Mid(strDate,3,2))
```

Comment: We still don't know if it's VBScript yet as their code suggests otherwise but this is a valid approach in VBScript. Use `DateSerial()` a lot, very effective.

Comment: Plus one. That'll work in VB6 or VBA as well - apart from the `WScript.Echo` which should be `Debug.Print` :)